# Welcome to The New Year WPSE, Here's Some 2015 Stats!

Tags: discussion

## Traffic

During 2015 WPSE had **21.6 million page views** with an average of **434,000** views a month!

## Questions and Answers

The highest voted question with **40 votes**, highest voted answer with **60 votes**, and most viewed question with **12,000+ views** all belongs to user [Christine Cooper](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/24875/christine-cooper) on [Disable emojicons introduced with WP 4.2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2).

- **[14,669 New Questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2015%20is%3Aquestion)**
- **[12,584 New Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2015%20is%3Aanswer)**
- Brings our overall QA Ratio to a [nice 71%!](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

[The top 3 tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/417511/top-tags-for-the-year) were:

- [[custom-post-types]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-post-types) with 1,328 Questions
- [[plugins]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) with 1,297 Questions
- [[php]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) with 1,126 Questions

The community ended up closing **[851 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/edit/418554)** this year and the three tags with the most closed questions in 2015 are:

- [[plugins]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) with 116 Closed Questions
- [[woocommerce]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) with 104 Closed Questions
- [[php]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) with 84 Closed Questions

## Users

This year **16,802 new users** joined the website but only **3,000** got about 50 rep. This brings our entirely user base to **60k users!**

The most active new user is [**jgraup**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/84219/jgraup) with 144 answers earning 1,795 rep.

The most active regular user is [**Pieter Goosen**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) with 473 answers earning 15,597 rep.

And most importantly, the user who unlocked the most hats during winter bash is [Pieter Goosen with 15 hats](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/wordpress.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Quite interesting to know about the hats. It is quite sad to see that so little (*less than 20%*) users got more than 50 rep, just wonder how many are still active in the site

Comment: BTW, thanks for the stats, you have now earned yourself a yearly job ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Only `850~` users who created their account before December this year ( and `Rep > 50` ) has accessed the site in December . Looks like a lot of the users are rep 101 though so they probably came from another site as a trusted user. If I do `Rep > 101` the number shoots down to `230~`. And just remind me next year lol, the [Data Explorer is pretty fun](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/queries)

Comment: SE has a nice API. You could probably automate such a report ;)

Comment: @MarkKaplun that would take the fun out of it. ;-)

Comment: It would be nice to see the top 100 Questions and top 100 answers of 2015. I imagine there are some pretty interesting things to remember in 2015.

Comment: @jgraup Here's all the [questions of 2015 sorted by votes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2015%20is%3aquestion) and all the [answers of 2015 sorted by votes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2015%20is%3aanswer)

Comment: @jgraup [Disabling Emojis by a long shot followed by multi-part emails](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/419427/top-favorites-of-year)