# Happy Late New Year! Here's Some 2016 Numbers!

Tags: discussion

Happy Late New Year everyone! Had to wait for Hats to finish so we knew who the true winners are :)

[2015 "stats" for comparison.](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4114/7355)

## Traffic

In 2016 The WordPress Stack Exchange had **23.3 million** page views, which is a ~8% increase from last year, with an average of **467,000** per month. <sup>[1](https://www.quantcast.com/wordpress.stackexchange.com#/trafficCard)</sup>

## Questions and Answers

In 2016 there were [**11,736 questions**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aquestion) asked [**12,897 answers**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aanswer) provided. Answers were on-par with last year which is nice but questions were on a bit of a downturn with ~20% decrease. Our QA ratio is still on the rise and is now sitting at a nice [**74%**](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

- The **Most Favorited** Question & **Most Upvoted** Question <sup>[2](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/612881/top-favorites-of-year)</sup> <sup>[3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aquestion)</sup>

  - [Adding Custom Text Patterns in the WP 4.5 Visual Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/223677/7355) by [jgraup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/84219/jgraup)
- The **Most Viewed** Question with ~35k Views

  - [Annoying JQMIGRATE: Migrate is in console after update to WP 4.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/224661/7355) by [dingo_d](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/58895/dingo-d)
- The **Most Upvoted** Answer <sup>[4](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aanswer)</sup>

  - [Get rid of Another update is currently in progress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226009/7355) by [Alexander Ushakov](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/93707/alexander-ushakov)

[2016 Questions sorted by votes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aquestion)
[2016 Answers sorted by votes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3A2016%20is%3Aanswer)

The top 3 tags of 2016 is:<sup>[5](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/417511/top-tags-for-the-year)</sup>

1. [[php]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) with 1,204 Questions
2. [[custom-post-types]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-post-types) with 1,015 Questions
3. [[plugins]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) with 969 Questions

Together we were able to close a total of [664 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/612893/number-of-closed-questions) which is a ~22% decrease from last year. The top tags in closed questions were: <sup>[6](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/612905/top-closed-tags-of-the-year)</sup>

1. [[plugins]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) with 96 Closed Questions
2. [[php]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) with 91 Closed Questions
3. [[woocommerce]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) with 64 Closed Questions

The above closed tags have not changed much since last year but has moved around bit in rankings.

## Users

This year [**19,535**](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/418552/number-user-joined-by-year) new users joined the website but only [**3,123**](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/612911/new-users-earning-more-than-50) earned more than 50 rep and only [**493**](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/612914/new-users-earning-more-than-101) users got above 101 rep ( 101 is the default "Trusted User Joins Community" reputation ). This brings our entirely user base to [**78k**](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) users!

The most active new user is [**Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/98212/ethan-jinks-osullivan) with 158 valued answers earning 2,699 rep!

The most active regular user is [**birgire**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) with 275 answers earning 11,322 rep!

Last, but not least, the user who earned the most hats during the 2016 Winter Bash is [toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) earning [18 hats](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/wordpress.stackexchange.com) followed closely behind by [Dave Romsey](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2807/dave-romsey) earning 17 hats!

Comment: I swear I took these hats en passant. I haven't actively searched for them.

Comment: toscho was probably hacking the system ;)

Comment: A good reminder that we should get rid of [tag:php] questions.

Comment: Just seeing this now. Good to know I made it into the 2016 stats.