# Looking Back at 2018 - Numbers and Info!

Tags: discussion

## Welcome to a new year!

Shoutout to all of those who participated this past year one way or another. Your contributions continue to make this site a great resource for WordPress information.

**Previous years**

**2018** | [2017](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4455/7355) | [2016](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4321/7355) | [2015](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4114/7355)

---

## Site Traffic

During 2018 we saw **31.6 million** global views with an average of ~700k unique views each month<sup>[1](https://www.quantcast.com/wordpress.stackexchange.com)</sup>. Our views site peaked in **September** and was at the lowest toward the beginning of the year in **January**. This is still a increase from previous years as it seems.

---

## Users

Throughout 2018 the site saw **21,301** new users get created.

- 2,808 or 13.1% of those users gained more than 50 reputation
- 348 or 1.6% of those users gained more than 101 reputation

This brings our site to (roughly) **121k** users in total!

The most active of these new users goes to **[Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj)** earning 3,851 reputation and reaching 24k people with their helpful posts!

The most active regular user goes to **[Jacob Peattie](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/110/year/wordpress/2018-01-01/39152?sort=reputationchange#39152)** earning 11,080 reputation last year. Their total posts reaching 244k people!

During the [2018 Winter Bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) the site as a whole earned 2,638 hats. The biggest hat hoarder being user **[butlerblog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/38603/butlerblog)** who sits high at #1 with 7 hats!

---

## Questions and Answers

Users asked a total of 12,328 questions, **[5,304 (43%)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2018%20answers%3A0)** went unanswered, and 2,784 were viewed positively with 1+ votes. There was also 10,549 helpful answers, **[5,699 answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20created%3A2018%20score%3A0)** currently don't have any votes. All in all this brings our site total questions to 92,793 and answers to 116,474!

- **The Most Favorited Question**

  - [How to: Make JWT-authenticated requests to the Wordpress API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/299542/7355) by [grazianodev](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/129417/grazianodev)
- **The Most Upvoted Question**

  - [Check if Gutenberg is currently in use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309862/check-if-gutenberg-is-currently-in-use) by [NerdOfLinux](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/123649/nerdoflinux)
- **The Most Viewed Question**

  - [400 bad request on admin-ajax.php only using wp_enqueue_scripts-action-hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/291301/7355) by [Sin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/129895/sin)
- **The Most Upvoted Answer**

  - [Can I upgrade a plugin to a specific version?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/290019/7355) by [kero](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/108180/kero)

The top tags of 2018 were:

- [woocommerce] which currently has [688 unanswered questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D%20created%3A2018%20answers%3A0)
- [plugins] which currently has [542 unanswered questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplugins%5D%20created%3A2018%20answers%3A0)
- [php] which currently has [486 unanswered questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20created%3A2018%20answers%3A0)

---

That wraps up 2018! We hope the coming year is just as good if not better than the last! Now we'll leave the answer section open with a question:

What WordPress related achievement or accomplishment were you most proud of in 2018? What WordPress feature or event are you most excited about in 2019?

Comment: 1.6% of new users earning more than 101 rep - is this similar for other niche SE sites or considered a low value?

Comment: @kero If we look at sites that have similar views/day ( Information Security and Software Engineering ) - their answer rates are in the 90%. Software Engineering had 9k more users registered than we did and 2.7% hit the 102 reputation mark. Raspberry Pi has a similar QA ratio to us and similar views per day but their new users for 2018 is 15k, 2.9% still hit 102 or more. If I were to guess based on similar sites we are probably on the low end of the spectrum.

Comment: The percentage seemed very low to me (probably because I myself am quite an active user), 1.6% doesn't seem too bad to me compared to 2.7% and 2.9%

Comment: _Site Traffic:this is still an increase from previous years as it seems._ It seems like this is wrong. According to 2017 year, SO had 32.1 million  views globally, but in 2018 it was 31.6 million. So it isn't an increase

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson well first off the post says "years" not "year", and it is an increase from 2016 and 2015. But yes 2017 had more views than 2018. Second - this site is *not* SO... it's Wordpress Development...

Comment: Damn. I wish I could see how many of these unanswered questions are actually "dumb" questions. Well, there's no such thing as a dumb question, really, everyone's gotta start somewhere, but some people lack the proper skill to word it correctly or present their issue in a good way, many times I find this to be harder than the question itself - how do I tell others what I have in mind? Can't imagine what it's gonna be like for a non-native english speaker.